# How to compute the following probability involving 4 normal random variables?

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian

$\alpha, \alpha', \beta$ and $\beta'$ are four independent standard normal random variables, I am wondering how to compute the probability of the following two events:

- $\alpha>\alpha'>0, \ \ \beta<\beta', \ \ |\alpha-\alpha'+\beta-\beta'|\geq c_1,$
- $\alpha>0>\alpha', \ \ \beta<\beta', \ \ |\alpha-\alpha'+\beta-\beta'|\geq c_1, \ \ |\frac{\alpha}{\alpha'}|>c_2$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are positive constants. I know that the sum and difference of normal random variables are still normal random variables, but I'm not sure how to use this with the inequality relation here.

Comment: These can be calculated with four-dimensional integrals, but they have no simple formulas.

Comment: Even the probabilities for simpler events, like $\alpha>0, \ \alpha+\beta>c_1$ or $\alpha-\alpha'>c_1,\ \alpha/\alpha'>c_2$ do not have simple formulas in terms of the usual functions for normal variables.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to simplify the formula so that we can have a lower bound of the probability?

Comment: what are you doing with these probabilities? There is trivially "a lower bound", so the question has to be whether there's a useful lower bound, and that will depend on your use for the probabilities.

Comment: @MattF. I am analyzing some machine learning algorithms and I want to say that parameters initialized as standard normal variables have the properties above with certain probability. So I guess any lower bound would be good for me.

Answer (score -1):

This might work, the pdf might have the answer or at least part of the question but could not find the rest. [https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter4.pdf](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Echance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter4.pdf)